# Some kind of Hom tensor adjoint

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

> Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$ module and $E$ be an injective module. Prove that $$\phi:M\otimes \text{Hom}(N,E)\rightarrow \text{Hom}(\text{Hom}(M,N),E)$$ given by $\phi(m\otimes f)(g)=f(g(m))$ is an isomorphism.

In case when $M$ is free, it comes easily with out the assumption of $E$ being injective.

Let $M=\oplus R$ then

$$M\otimes \text{Hom}(N,E)\cong (\oplus R)\otimes \text{Hom}(N,E)\cong\oplus(R\otimes \text{Hom}(N,E))\cong\oplus(\text{Hom}(N,E))$$
$$\text{Hom}(\text{Hom}(M,N),E)\cong \text{Hom}(\text{Hom}(\oplus R,N),E)
\cong \oplus\text{Hom}( \text{Hom}(R,N),E)\cong\oplus(\text{Hom}(N,E))$$

But in general, I am not able to give an inverse map..

Only hints please.

It has been confirmed by the instructor  that there is a typo in the question and it is finitely presented.

Comment: Is the ring $A$ assumed noetherian?

Comment: $A$ is not given to be noetherian

Comment: Then I think you need $M$ to be finitely presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note.* Answer edited after the OP stated that $M$ is to be assumed finitely presented ratherthan only finitely generated.

---

The fact that the two groups are isomorphic is not sufficient to establish that $\DeclareMathOperator\H{Hom}\phi$ is an isomorphism; however, you can (tediously) check that if $\alpha\colon M\otimes\H(N,E)\to\oplus(\H(N,E))$ is the top isomorphism and $\beta\colon\H(\H(M,N),E)\to\oplus(\H(N,E))$ is the bottom one, then $\beta\phi=\alpha$, so also $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

However, you can do without such a tedious check. Suppose $M=M_1\oplus M_2$ and call $\phi$, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ the corresponding maps. You can check that the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
M\otimes\H(N,E) @>>> (M_1\otimes\H(N,E))\oplus (M_2\otimes\H(N,E)) \\
@V{\phi}VV @VV{(\phi_1,\phi_2)}V \\
\H(\H(M,N),E) @>>> \H(\H(M_1,N),E)\oplus\H(\H(M_2,N),E)
\end{CD}
$$
is commutative. The horizontal maps are defined in the obvious way and they are isomorphisms.

Thus $\varphi$ is an isomorphism if and only if $(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ is an isomorphism, that is, if and only if both $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are isomorphisms.

You can use this for the induction step in proving the statement for $M=A^n$, which doesn't require $E$ to be injective.

Next, consider $M$ finitely presented and an exact sequence $0\to K\to A^n\to M\to 0$. This produces the exact sequences
$$
K\otimes\H(N,E)\to A^n\otimes\H(N,E)\to M\otimes\H(N,E)\to0
$$
and
$$
0\to\H(M,N)\to\H(A^n,N)\to\H(K,N)
$$
Since $E$ is injective, the latter sequence produces the exact sequence
$$
\H(\H(K,N),E)\to \H(\H(A^n,N),E)\to \H(\H(M,N),E)\to0
$$
and we finally get the commutative diagram
$$
\begin{CD}
K\otimes\H(N,E)@>>> A^n\otimes\H(N,E)@>>> M\otimes\H(N,E) @>>> 0 \\
@V{\phi_K}VV @V{\phi_{A^n}}VV @V{\phi_M}VV \\
\H(\H(K,N),E) @>>> \H(\H(A^n,N),E) @>>> \H(\H(M,N),E) @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
The middle vertical map $\phi_{A^n}$ is an isomorphism, as shown before. By diagram chasing, $\phi_M$ is surjective. Note that we have made no special hypothesis on $M$, other than it's finitely generated.

As $M$ is finitely presented, then also $K$ is finitely generated and so $\phi_K$ is surjective. By diagram chasing, $\phi_M$ is injective.

Comment: It is worth noting that the statement is (at least) true, if we assume $M$ to be finitely presented.

Comment: @user218931 Yes, of course the argument applies in this case.

Comment: Nothing is given about $M$  except $M$ is finitely generated.. I will try to understand this and come back to you.. thanks

Comment: It has been confirmed by the instructor  that there is a typo in the question and it is finitely presented.